# How to activate the detection of duplicate blocks of statements in a Go source with Jetbrains Goland?

Tags: goland

I've opened a *Go* source where functions have many blocks of statements in common.

- When I use *IntelliJ* with *Sonarlint* (with *Java* and not *Go*)
  common blocks of statements are marked with gray signs.
  (I had nothing to do: *IntelliJ* was immediately detecting them)
- When I use *Goland 2023.3.5* with *Sonarlint*, no detection is made, and nothing is shown.

I searched among *Goland* inspections and *Sonarlint* rules for *Go*, but I didn't found where to activate this detection.

It must be obvious, but where is it?
Thanks!